# Launching a project from existing files in PhpStorm

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

I just restart with PhpStorm after a year and a half of break. I created a PHP project with the framework Symfony following [their own tutorial](https://symfony.com/download) which include to create a new project with the command line.

When I start PhpStorm I can't launch the new project from "open" option. It simply does nothing after choosing the files from the new project folder.

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

**Therefore, how are we able to launch a project from existing files in PhpStorm?**

I tried to create a new project despite not having the Symfony framework. Yet, I am not even able to create a new file :

[image].

Yet,

I think it is a writing in files permission issue beause I use Ubuntu. yet when I follow the [tutorial from openclassrooms](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony), I don't achieve to grant Symfony the permission to write in the files :

```
:/var$ sudo chmod +a "www-data allow, delete, write, append, file_inherit, directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs && sudo chmod +& "'whoami' allow, delete, write, append, file_inherit, directory_inherit, directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
[3] 17384
'whoami' allow, delete, write, append, file_inherit, directory_inherit, directory_inherit: command not found

[3]+  Stopped                 sudo chmod +a "www-data allow, delete, write, append, file_inherit, directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs && sudo chmod +
```

Comment: So you created a new Symfony project according to Symfony's tutorial and now want to "import" it as a completely new in into PhpStorm?

Comment: So .. after you click on "OK" button IDE just does nothing? So far it looks like file permission issue (look at small "lock" icons of bottom right corner of the folder icon -- it's present on many of them). But better check the `idea.log` for hints (`Help | Show Log in XXX` -- or https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)

Comment: @HonzaRydrych Yes exactly

Comment: @LazyOne Yes that's sounds as aperfect plausible hypothesis as far as there exists two command lines to deald with those file permission issue which created some problems : `rm -rf app/cache/* && rm -rf app/log/*` and `sudo chmod +a "www-data allow, delete, write, append, file_inherit, directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs && sudo chmod +& "`whoami `allow, delete, write, append, file_inherit, directori_inherit, directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs`

Comment: You definitely have permission issues. Possibly it's related to the way how you launch PhpStorm (different user or something?). Try granting more relaxed permission to that folder (it's your local PC -- it does not have not be that tight as on real server).

Comment: But if there are permission issues, how would the Symfony installer be able to install the Symfony project in that folder?

Comment: @HonzaRydrych The answer is from "Droits d'accès" section in this French website : https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony/symfony-un-framework-php

I have an issue with the `cut: the delimiter must be a single character`. I don't know if I'm going in the good direction or if I'm missing something more connected to PHPStorm

Comment: Ahh, I understand - you have to set rights to /var folder because your httpd (apache, nginx,...) has to have create files here. But it's something completely different from your issue.

Comment: @HonzaRydrych God ! Thanks ! But What should I do ?

Comment: Sorry, if my comment looked unappropriated - i didn't mean it that way. I just wanted to advice you, not to follow wrong path.

Comment: @HonzaRydrych No it's okay :) I actually mean it ! It's great to know what is the issue. But actually how can I cope with it now ?

Comment: I'm thinking about user under which runs javaVM on your computer (because PhpStorm is java app). If the Symfony's installer was able to write files into the project folder, you can (I assume) edit files in that folder, with some text editor, than the problem must be the privileges which has the user who runs JVM/PhpStorm. Can you try open/edit some file anywhere in your filesystem with PhpStorm? In your home folder for example?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I move the whole project, give him `chown username:username ./ -R` and it worked, without apache though. Yet I don't know how to see him now on an internet page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134877/discussion-between-honza-rydrych-and-jaures-ulm).